# Docker crashes on startup and can't be found by service

Tags: docker

I installed Docker Desktop on Ubuntu 22.04 following the instructions on the official Docker website. `which docker` yields `/usr/local/bin/docker`.

However, since then, Docker Desktop consistently crashes on system startup. During this time, running docker commands in the console reveals that the Docker daemon is seemingly not running.

I have to manually launch the Docker Desktop application before being able to use docker commands in the console.

Even after this, running `(sudo) service docker status` yields `Unit docker.service could not be found`. This is completely absurd as I literally have two images running locally while this is happening!

Whatever is causing this problem seems to also be causing other programs (such as `aws lightsail`) to not be able to detect the docker service properly.

Note: I have virtualisation enabled in my BIOS, and Docker auto-start is enabled in my Docker Desktop settings.

Comment: Docker Desktop has a GUI and a hidden Linux VM, but neither of these are really necessary on a native-Linux host.  Could you use the standalone Docker Engine instead?